# Jupyter doesn't recognize torchaudio

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am trying to install `torchaudio` to use in a Jupyter notebook but when i import it i get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchaudio'
```

I tried to import it in a `.py` file that the notebook uses but to with no success. I thought maybe it wasnt installed properly but when i try to install it using `pip install torchaudio` i get "requirement already satisfied".

Im lost, how can i import it successfully?

Comment: How do you run your Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean, but i run it on a server. I use virtual environment and i added `torchaudio` there too

Comment: If you type `!pip list` inside a cell of your Jupyter Notebook, is `torchaudio` listed?

Comment: if i type it with the `!` then it shows `pip install torchaudio list
Collecting torchaudio
  Using cached torchaudio-0.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement list (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for list`

Comment: Just type `!pip list` (list is the name of the pip command not the name of a library) not `!pip install torchaudio list`

Comment: The above output is what i get after typing `!pip list` if i type `pip list` torchaudio doesnt show but neither does `torch` and i dont have any problems using `torch`

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install torchaudio
```

should return:

```
Collecting torchaudio
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/34/c651430dea231e382ddf2eb5773239bf4885d9528f640a4ef39b12894cb8/torchaudio-0.6.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.7MB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 6.7MB 2.4MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torchaudio) (1.6.0+cu101)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torch==1.6.0->torchaudio) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from torch==1.6.0->torchaudio) (1.18.5)
Installing collected packages: torchaudio
Successfully installed torchaudio-0.6.0
```

And everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have jupyter installed on your virual environment (where torchaudio is installed). If you do not have, it is likely that you're launching jupyter from your root env and therefore, jupyter is using your root env (which do not have torchaudio installed)

This is a very common mistake. You can solve by pip installing jupyter in the env that torchaudio is installed and launching jupyter from there.

You can always check which jupyter you're launching by running the command:

```sh
which jupyter
```